# Force developer to use string from special class

Tags: c#

I have an `ObjectResult` that will return an error message if an error occurs.
I’d like the developer not to be able to type their own message into this; they should have to use one of a set of predetermined message string in a special class (just to manage message).

For example, I don’t want this to be possible:

```
ObjectResult obj = new ObjectResult() {Message = "xxx"};
```

A developer should have to write:

```
ObjectResult obj = new ObjectResult() {Message = MessagesStore.SomeMessage};
```

How can I implement something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare an enum and decorate entries with description attributes

```
public enum MessagesStore
{ 
    [Description("Everything is Ok")]
    Ok,
    [Description("Everything is not Ok")]
    NotOk
}
```

Use the following extension method

```
 public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string GetEnumDescription(this Enum value)
    {
        var fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        var attributes =
            (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
            false);

        if (attributes != null &&
            attributes.Length > 0)
        {
            return attributes[0].Description;
        }

        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

And, an example of usage:

```
var ms = MessagesStore.Ok;
var desc = ms.GetEnumDescription();
```

desc with be "Everything is Ok"

Comment: Is there another way to solve this problem? Because if we use `Decription` of enum, it is a const string, cannot be changed at run time. Example, if I need set file path to message "The file 'abc.jpg' does not exist" (abc.jpg is provided at runtime), it can be done with enum decription

Answer (score 1):

You could declare the MessagesStore of Type [`Enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) inside the ObjectResult class,

```
enum MessagesStore
    {
    None,
    Error,
    ok,      
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use like this:

```
    public class MessagesStore
    {
        public class Error
        {
            public const string Error1= "Error1";
            public const string Error2= "Error2";
        }
        public class Warning
        {
            public const string Warning1 = "Warning1";
            public const string Warning2 = "Warning2";
        }
    }
```

and then you can access message :

```
ObjectResult obj = new ObjectResult() {Message = MessagesStore.Error.Error1};
```

Comment: A custom class is a much better idea.  Enums cannot hold string values. +1

Comment: @LolCoder. Can we access `MessagesStore` class like this without declaring it static?

Comment: @LolCoder consts is a good way to store strings, but this won't solve t4nhpt's problem because you still can assign anything you want to `Message`

Comment: @Dima : Sorry if I misunderstood the question. But as far from my analysis,OPs simply want to access the message from special class(holds all message), not inlining the message directly,Right?

Comment: @LolCoder re-read question again, and looks like I might be wrong :)

Comment: If we use this way, developer can still assign anything to `Message`.

Answer (score 1):

You may put a collection of available strings into `enum`

```
public enum MessageString
{
  [Description("Message one")]
  Message1,
  [Description("Message two")]
  Message2,
}
```

and then either change `Message` property to return `MessageString` type or remove default constructor and require to pass a `MessageString` parameter:

```
public class ObjectResult
{
  public MessageString Message { get; set;}  
}

public class ObjectResult
{
  public string Message { get; private set;}  

  public ObjectResult(MessageString message)
  {
    Message = message.GetDescription();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd combine both the `strings` and the `enums` to force the user to use the already specified text. This is only a bit different approach, without using `Attributes`:

Add in the `ObjectResult` class:

```
public enum InfoMessages
{
   Error1,
   Error2,
   Warning1,
   Warning2
};
```

Then edit `ObjectResult` class constructor with `Messages` parameter:

```
public ObjectResult(InfoMessages message)
{
   SetMessage(message);
}
```

Then make the method to set the correct string according to given enum:

```
public void SetMessage(InfoMessages message)
{
    switch (message)
    {
       case InfoMessages.Error1: this.Message = "Error message for Error1"; break;
       case InfoMessages.Error2: this.Message = "Error message for Error2"; break;
       // ...
    }
}
```